# How to pause screen recording with cmd+5 in Mojave

Tags: screen-capture, quicktime, mojave

I need to start using screencast recording and know that we can use Quick Time for this. However, in Mojave we have the improved built-in feature of taking screenshots or record screen with the <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>. It adds a nice feature that is showing when we click the mouse, where we cannot do this with Quick Time.

However, I didn't find a way to pause the recording like we can do in Quick Time.

Is there any way to use the <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> for recording screen but pausing the recording?